# How to keeping Jupyter notebook awake and running even when PC goes to sleep

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

How do I keep my ML code running in the background in Anaconda Jupyter notebook even if my PC goes to sleep? Is there a way? Note: I do not want to change my sleep settings to sleep never.

Comment: Please be reasonable and don't ask for the impossible! Are you aware what is the meaning of "sleep'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not think that is possible! The training should be suspended when the machine is in sleep. It will resume the calculations seamlessly right after the machine awakes.

While this is the generic behavior and you do not like it, other options can be thought of depending on how are you running the Jupyter notebook, in local? Then which operating systems? behavior in mac os is different from ubuntu when sleep. In mac you can use `caffeinate python ...` to keep the machine from sleeping till this script runs.

Another thing is, is it possible to just do just "display sleep" in mac os. Then the background process keeps running. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you @Haramoz for your answer. I am running the code in my local windows 10.I wonder how this issue have not been taken into consideration yet

Comment: Well, I guess because its not really an "issue", if you want to make your computer to work, why put it in sleep? This challenges the very notion of sleep to some extend. I think what you want to achieve is a new customized "sleep" function. It seems mac os is most advanced in that direction right now. Good luck in your search.

Comment: How to configure Jupyter to prefix Python cells with `caffeinate` ? That is, only `caffeinate` when a cell is running, but allow sleep after it completes.

Comment: `caffeinate` is a command line utility. To use it in Jupyter you _probably_ can prepend a bang symbol: `!caffeinate....`. If you have an idea how long your process will take you can use an explicit time argument, e.g. in a shell try `caffeinate -t 3600 &`. The time is in seconds so this example is for an hour. The ampersand just sends this process to the background so you can type new commands before it finishes.

Comment: when my computer goes to sleep, there is no kernel and I get the information in jupyter "Dismiss server" which I can only confirm..

Answer (score 0):

If your system is windows 10, just set the sleep/screen saver to the time you need for your model to work, or just put it as "never" go to sleep.  Whenever you are done you can change your settings back to what you need them to be.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way other than keeping your computer from sleeping.

Answer (score 0):

As you've been told already, you can't train your model while your PC actually sleeps. But there's a workaround for the second part of the question ("I do not want to change my sleep settings to sleep never"). You can prevent Windows from sleeping while a function is running. The solution is given here: https://gist.github.com/kbarnes3/3fb7d353e9bdd3efccd5.
Save this code in a file called powermanagement.py and then you can import it in a notebook and use it with a decorator, like this:

```py
from powermanagement import long_running

@long_running
def train_my_model():
    # call the long training process here...

train_my_model()
```

This will keep Windows awake until the function is running and once it finished the PC will go to sleep again.